# @Html.Action causes javascript to load multiple times

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I inherited an application and trying to figure out way `scripts` on the tabs are loading more than once.

It is an basic bootstrap tab feature that loads partial views.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#reputation" data-toggle="tab">Reputation</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
     @Html.Action("SocialConfig", "Admin", new {area = "Admin", accountID = ViewBag.AccountID})
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="reputation">
      @Html.Action("ReputationConfig", "Admin", new { area = "Admin", accountID = ViewBag.AccountID })
     </div>
</div>
```

There is an `JavaScript` file included on each partial view. Each script will get loaded as many times there are `@Html.Action`
So for instance I have 2 `@Html.Action` so the script on the `SocialConfig` view will load twice and the script on the `ReputationConfig` will also load twice.

How can i stop this silly behavior.

Comment: Are the actions returning PartialViews or Views?

Comment: @RussellYoung they are return PartialViews -  (return PartialView("_SocialConfig");)

Comment: And are the scripts in an `@section Scripts` block?

Comment: Nope i just checked the pages, and the scripts are just added at the top of the page no @section Scripts

Comment: @RussellYoung, i just added the section to see if it makes a difference, still get the same

Comment: Yes its odd - I'm wondering if it's due to it being in the tabs - can you try moving one of them above the `<ul>` and see if you see the same behaviour?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117136/discussion-between-russell-young-and-r4nc1d).

Comment: Scripts should never be in partial views. Only in the main view or its layout.

Comment: This behavior occurs because `@Html.Action` basically starts the action at the controller and returns the view it's supposed to return. If that view contains a script tag with Javascript, the script tag will get rendered as many times as the action is being called.

Answer (score 0):

When working with partialview try to avoid loading script, add it instead in the main view. Why not just add it in the current view?

Comment: dont want everything in the same view as the view will get way to big.

Comment: Is it library used by all views like bootstrap, or is it custom script used by these views?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery to add some event handlers then check if the  selectors are filtering elements of both partials views. If so you should change your selector in way that it is contextualized to your partial view.

Ex:

Partial view 1

```
<div>
    <button class="button" type="button">Click me</button>
</div>
<script>
     $(".button").click(function () { alert("click on button") });
</script>
```

Partial view 2

```
<div>
    <a class="button">Click me</a>
</div>
<script>
     $(".button").click(function () { alert("click on link") });
</script>
```

A example of contextualized events:

Partial view 1

```
<div id="my-partial-view-1-container">
    <button class="button" type="button">Click me</button>
</div>
<script>
     $("#my-partial-view-1-container").find(".button").click(function () { alert("click on button") });
</script>
```

Partial view 2

```
<div id="my-partial-view-2-container">
    <a class="button">Click me</a>
</div>
<script>
     $("#my-partial-view-2-container").find(".button").click(function () { alert("click on link") });
</script>
```